# Spring integration: discardChannel doesn't work for filter of integration flow

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I faced with a problem when I create IntegrationFlow dynamically using DSL.
If discardChannel is defined as message channel object and if the filter returns false - nothing happens (the message is not sent to specified discard channel)
The source is:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("SIMPLE_CHANNEL")
private MessageChannel simpleChannel;

IntegrationFlow integrationFlow = IntegrationFlows.from("channelName")
  .filter(simpleMessageSelectorImpl, e -> e.discardChannel(simpleChannel))
  .get();

...

@Autowired
@Qualifier("SIMPLE_CHANNEL")
private MessageChannel simpleChannel;

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow simpleFlow() {
   return IntegrationFlows.from(simpleChannel)
   .handle(m -> System.out.println("Hello world"))
   .get();

@Bean(name = "SIMPLE_CHANNEL")
public MessageChannel simpleChannel() {
  return new DirectChannel();
}
```

But if the discard channel is defined as name of the channel, everything works.
Debuging I found that mentioned above the part of the code:

```
IntegrationFlow integrationFlow = IntegrationFlows.from("channelName")
   .filter(simpleMessageSelectorImpl, e -> e.discardChannel(simpleChannel))
   .get();
```

returns flow object which has map with integrationComponents and one of the component which is FilterEndpointSpec has "handler" field of type MessageFilter with discardChannel = null, and discardChannelName = null;
But if discard channel is defined as name of the channel the mentioned field "handler" with discardChannel=null but discardChannelName="SIMPLE_CHANNEL", as result everything works good.

It is behavior of my running application. Also I wrote the test and in test everything works good for both cases (the test doesn't run all spring context so maybe it is related to any conflict there)

Maybe someone has idea what it can be.

The spring boot version is 2.1.8.RELEASE, spring integration is 5.1.7.RELEASE

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour you describe is indeed incorrect and made me wonder, but after testing it out I can't seem to reproduce it, so perhaps there is something missing from the information you provided. In any event, here is the complete app that I've modeled after yours which works as expected. So perhaps you can compare and see if something jumps:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class IntegrationBootApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(IntegrationBootApp.class, args);
        MessageChannel channel = context.getBean("channelName", MessageChannel.class);
        PollableChannel resultChannel = context.getBean("resultChannel", PollableChannel.class);
        PollableChannel discardChannel = context.getBean("SIMPLE_CHANNEL", PollableChannel.class);

        channel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo").build());
        System.out.println("SUCCESS: " + resultChannel.receive());

        channel.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("bar").build());
        System.out.println("DISCARD: " + discardChannel.receive());

    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("SIMPLE_CHANNEL")
    private PollableChannel simpleChannel;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {
        IntegrationFlow integrationFlow = IntegrationFlows.from("channelName")
                   .filter(v -> v.equals("foo"), e -> e.discardChannel(simpleChannel))
                   .channel("resultChannel")
                   .get();
        return integrationFlow;
    }

    @Bean(name = "SIMPLE_CHANNEL")
    public PollableChannel simpleChannel() {
      return new QueueChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public PollableChannel resultChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel(10);
    }
}
```

with output

> - SUCCESS: GenericMessage [payload=foo, headers={id=cf7e2ef1-e49d-1ecb-9c92-45224d0d91c1, timestamp=1576219339077}]
> - DISCARD: GenericMessage [payload=bar, headers={id=bf209500-c3cd-9a7c-0216-7d6f51cd5f40, timestamp=1576219339078}]

Comment: Thank you, it has weird behavior, I will try to investigate more the problem

Comment: We need to see more of your configuration. You said that you do a *dynamic flow*, so show how that happens. It even would be better to have some simple Spring Boot project from you to let us to reproduce and play with. It sounds more like you create a flow too early - far before that `simpleChannel` property is injected, therefore you set a `null` into that `discardChannel()` option. For now you indeed should go with the name until we figure out what is wrong with your config.

Comment: I refactored a bit a code of application and was surprised because discardChannel started working even If I pass there a bean. I tried to cancel some changes in order to find out in which moment the problem disappear but couldn't detect it. So seems the problem was with my code. (Just in case the dynamic flows I run on ApplicationStartedEvent event). Thanks for help!